# Class not find or load main class in cmd line while running standalone java program

Tags: java, mysql

my project structure

```
ProjectName
|--lib
|--Src
    |__Com
        |_Sample
            |_project
               |_.java files .....
```

I am running a standalone java program in cmd line

Firts i compiled it this below, got no error

```
d:\ProjectName\src\com\Sample\project> javac -cp d:\projectName\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;d:\projectName\lib\mysql-connector.jar; 
JdbcConnection.java Constants.java PropertiesUtil.java Metrics.java
```

So i tried executing program like below

```
d:\ProjectName\src\com\Sample\project> java -cp d:\projectName\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;d:\projectName\lib\mysql-connector.jar; 
JdbcConnection.java Constants.java PropertiesUtil.java Metrics.java
```

Gives me error saying

```
Error:Class not find or load main class JdbcConnection.java
```

What should i do for this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: `java JdbcConnection` not `java JdbcConnection.java`.

Comment: Besides potential spelling problems: your java command needs to have **all** classes in the classpath. For your second call you do **not** have anything that points to the directory where you have your freshly compiled classes!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: @GhostCat Can you explain with some example?

Comment: Sorry, but please learn to use the information that was **already** given to you. You have by now two other questions which explain in **great** detail how these things work. Do not expect us to explain it **again** to you, just because you prefer to be taught, instead of doing the learning yourself!